# Decrypt OS X Time Machine in Linux

Tags: ubuntu, encryption, time-machine

Is is possible to decrypt an encrypted Time Machine backup with Ubuntu Linux? If so, how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes there is a way to mount a FileVault2 encrypted disk under Linux called **libfvde**, it uses the fuse Filesystem layer, but it is still experimental code.

The project is located here: https://github.com/libyal/libfvde

If you are interested in the detailed analysis of FileVault2 which lead to this implementation look here: http://eprint.iacr.org/2012/374.pdf